# Is centralized deployment supported for outlook web-addins

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

Can we deploy outlook web-addins for O365 accounts using centralized deployment as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment) ?

Three/Four months before, if I tried to install outlook add-in using this method, installation itself would fail. Now, I don't get any errors while installing, but the add-in does not appear in Outlook clients (Outlook 2016 in Windows and OWA in browsers).

Are centralized deployments supported for Outlook add-ins now? Also, are there any client side requirements?  I found some related information [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Determine-if-Centralized-Deployment-of-add-ins-works-for-your-Office-365-organization-B4527D49-4073-4B43-8274-31B7A3166F92). But I am doubtful if it is up-to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the query bala. Centralized deployment for Outlook add-ins is not supported as of now and will come very soon. There are no specific client requirements other than minimum requirements for add-ins.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.